# Local: Calling functions from "outside" and from "inside"?

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme, racket, local

Can I call a function that is *inside* a `local` from the "outside"? Lets say we have the function A. It calls a fuction that is inside a local. Function A is not in that local. Is this possible?

Or is a function that is inside `local` able to call a function, that is "outside" of that `local`?

I know that one of these arguments is false but I can't remember which one of them and *why*. Can someone please explain to me which one is correct and *why*?

(Racket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use local bindings outside of its scope unless you explicitly expose them through upward or downward funarg or mutate bindings with local closures. Example:

```scm
(define (test n)
  (local [(define (helper from acc)
            (if (> from n)
                acc
                (helper (add1 from) (cons from acc))))]
    (helper 1 '())))

(test 5) ; ==> (5 4 3 2 1)
```

There is no way to access or call `helper` from outside of `test-sum` since it is local to `test-sum` and not passed or returned.

```scm
(define (upward funarg1 n)
  (local [(define (helper from acc)
            (if (> from n)
                acc
                (helper (add1 from) (cons from acc))))]
    (funarg1 helper)))

(define (test funarg2)
  (funarg2 1 '()))

(upward test 5) ; ==> (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Here the `helper` is passed as an argument to a callback. Here you are making the local `helper` available to `test`. The closures of the two are different, thus `test` doesn't have `n` since they don't share any lexical variables.

```scm
(define (downward n)
  (local [(define (helper from acc)
            (if (> from n)
                acc
                (helper (add1 from) (cons from acc))))]
    helper))

(define from-helper (downward 5))
(from-helper 1 '())   ; ==> (5 4 3 2 1)

((downward 10) 5 '()) ; ==> (10 9 8 7 6 5)
```

Here you return the helper. The global scope will not have access to `n` in `helper` but they can call it and it will work the same as if it was called inside.  The variables in the `helper` seem to be dead since the `downward` is finished, but Scheme keeps the lexical scope so `n` and `helper` will be available from `helper` as long as it exists.

```scm
(define exposed #f)
(define (mutate n)
  (local [(define (helper from acc)
            (if (> from n)
                acc
                (helper (add1 from) (cons from acc))))]
    (set! exposed helper)))

(mutate 5)
(exposed 1 '()) ; ==> (5 4 3 2 1)
```

This is just a variation of downward funarg. Instead of returning it mutates the global (or lexical) variable `exposed` which the code that has that as either global, lexical or free variable will be able to call after `(mutate 5)` has done its thing.

Comment: I thought upward funarg is the one returned from the inside environment frame to the outside; and downward funarg is the one passed to a function as an argument, used on the inside. Wikipedia [seems to agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem).

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help

```
#lang racket

(define (A x)
  (local [(define (localA y)
            (printf "localA ~a ~a\n" x y)
            (printf "i can call B\n")
            ;; here we see localA, A, and B
            (B (+ 1 x)))]
    ;; here we see localA, A, and B
    (localA (* x 2))))     

(define (B x)
  (local [(define (localB y)
            (printf "localB ~a ~a\n" x y)
            (printf "i can call A\n")
            ;; here we see localB, B, and A
            (A (+ 1 x)))]
    ;; here we see localB, B, and A
    (localB (* x 3))))

(A 0)

; localA 0 0
; i can call B
; localB 1 3
; i can call A
; localA 2 4
; i can call B
; localB 3 9
; i can call A
; localA 4 8
; i can call B
; localB 5 15
; i can call A
; localA 6 12
; i can call B
; localB 7 21
; ...
```

`A` cannot call `localB` and `B` cannot call `localA`

Comment: I think this answer is very close to what the OP is looking for, but with the minor issue that they are likely talking about the [`local`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Flocal..rkt%29._local%29%29) form, which is used since the HtDP teaching languages don’t permit arbitrary internal definitions. I think, if you insert uses of `local` where you use internal definitions, your example could remain more or less the same.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and the code. But I don't quite get it. I don't see any `local` in your code. So as far as I remember it: It *is possible* to call a function from inside local that is *outside* but the other way around isn't, correct?

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of this form. Thanks Alexis. Sorry if I confused you, Jacques – I'll remove this answer shortly.

Comment: no need to remove this answer at all. it is to the point, as @AlexisKing pointed out, just need to wrap the internal `define` forms inside a `local`. purely a syntax issue.

Answer (score 2):

Any new scope is created *nested* inside its enclosing scope.

[image]

Any identifier in *a scope region* is also inside *its* enclosing scope and can use any other identifier in that same scope or its enclosing scopes.

[image]

You can't use an identifier outside of its scope; but you can use a *value* it referred to, by returning that value "upward", from that inner scope.

[image]